# How to see the content of a variable in a script that acts as a listener: Facebook real time update

Tags: php, facebook, real-time, server-side

I have two files, index.php and a callback.php. Index.php is used to display data on the website. The callback.php is a script that acts like a listener. The callback.php is called by a server and the $update variable in callback.php is updated by the server in real time. I want to see the contents of $update variable every time it updates.

Callback.php:

```
    if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' &&
        $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN) {
      echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];

    } else if ($method == 'POST') {
       $updates = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
       //I want to see the content of $updates
       // resend the push notification again.
        error_log('updates = ' . print_r($updates, true));
     }
```

How can i do this? Please let me know. I would appreciate if you have some sample code i could start with.

Answer (score 1):

The technique I believe you are describing is called long-polling.

Basically, the client sends an ajax request to the server and sits there waiting for a response. Upon some event (this is where SSJS like Node comes in really handy), the server sends the client the new data. Upon receiving the data, the client immediately sends a new request and waits for the next update.

Here is the flow:

**Page loads:**

```
 __________                              _________
|          |                            |         |
| Client A | ---> Request for Data ---> | Server  |
|__________|                            |_________|
```

**Then what? Suspense:**

```
 __________                              _________
|          |                            |         |
| Client A | .......................... | Server  |
| waiting  |                            | waiting |
|__________|                            |_________|
```

**Someone else updates content you want to see in real time:**

```
                     __________
                    |          |
                    | Client B |
                    |__________|
                         |
                         | Sends update to Server
                         |___________________.
                                             |
                                             V
 __________                              _________
|          |                            |         |
| client A | ............<------------- | Server  |
| waiting  |                            | Reacts  |
|__________|                            |_________|
     |
     |
     V    
 __________                              _________
|          |                            |         |
| Client A |   ( No open connection)    | Server  |
| Updates  |                            | Idle... |
|__________|                            |_________|
     |
     |
     V
 ___________                              _________
|           |                            |         |
| Client A  |                            |         |
| Reacts to |                            | Server  |
| Update    | ---> Request for Data ---> |         |
|___________|                            |_________|
```

**Rinse, Repeat**
The thing to remember here is that HTTP1.1 supports a persistent connection, meaning it won't timeout unless you want it to. I'd recommend looking into [NodeJS](http://www.nodejs.org) on your server side to trigger these events.

Comment: yes...this seems to somewhat what i am looking for. My index.php susbscribes for some real time data to the server and the callback url is callback.php. the server send the change notification to callback.php. I want to see the change notification which is stored in $updates.

Comment: when you say server side do u mean the server itself or the callback.php file? i do not control the server that sends the change notification to callback.php.

Comment: You have to have some kind of event listener on the server. PHP is generally not the best solution for listeners because of the blocking I/O. For example, if you wanted your PHP script to check the database every second for new posts from other users, you'd have to use `sleep(1000)`, which halts the script and prevents other scripts from running. This is one of the main benefits of NodeJS.